How equirectangular panorama is created from a set of fisheye images?
I need neither code nor program instruction how to make this. I am looking for at least some intuition, which I completely do not get here.
https://paulbourke.net/dome/dualfish2sphere/
I am using this tutorial for self-study. I have also implemented mapping between normalized equirectangular and fisheye coordinates. But... what now? When I have several cameras with different positions & rotations, how do I decide which gets projected to which part of the output image? How do I unnormalize the resulting coordinates? It seems that I am stuck at this last step of using camera position at the projection process.

This question is similar to: How are virtual tour photos taken?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This answer is not specific to two fish eye photographs.
Bunt in general the best approach is using Hugin https://hugin.sourceforge.io/
If your images have a strong black zone, you probably need to crop it before using them.
You need enough reference points between the images. The software then allows you to see two overlapped images and determine common points between them, the tip of a plant, a small rock, etc.
The page itself has some tutorials. https://hugin.sourceforge.io/tutorials/index.shtml
If you are still experimenting, I would recommend not using only two fish eye photos, but at least 6 in 90° (to form a cube) You will greatly improve the resolution and detail of the final image.
I have not tested it with different-resolution images or different focal lengths.
